# Any way to restore 3D effect and/or shading to UIPopoverController?

Tags: ios7, uipopovercontroller

The recent release of iOS 7 includes a change to `UIPopoverController` where the popovers are now flat, with no shading underneath (none of the betas for iOS 7 included this change - the change only appeared with the GM release). Unfortunately this change is really not working with our iPad application; without the shading effect and the dark border, our popover is blending in with the underlying screen.

Do I have any options at all as far as customizing this effect or (even better) making popover look the way it used to look?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `popoverBackgroundViewClass`. Not sure this will give you the result you are looking for, however. When a popover is displayed, the system dims the background view hierarchy, but there are no shadows underneath the popover. If this is not enough, you should look at implementing a custom popover controller or using an open source.